# Overriding jOOQ's exception handling for UpdatableRecords

Tags: java, sql, activerecord, jooq

I'm using jOOQ v2.6 as I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and there is a bug in jOOQ v3.1 which causes code generation to fail.  (I'm aware this will be fixed in v3.2).

From the manual:

```
// Create a new record
BookRecord book1 = create.newRecord(BOOK);

// Insert the record: INSERT INTO BOOK (TITLE) VALUES ('1984');
book1.setTitle("1984");
book1.store();
```

If store() fails, a DataAccessException is thrown.  In my case I would simply like the process to sleep until either the CRUD operation works, or I observe the issue and intervene.  This means that I need to wrap every instance of BookRecord.store() in a try/catch.  This then applies to all CRUD operations, across all UpdatableRecords.

Is there a simple way that I can handle all CRUD DataAccessExceptions for all generated Record types, without having to remember to implement the same exception handler over and over again?

Comment: Does code generation really fail in v3.1? If you're [referring to this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/eEOgoCJf0xU), then I think the problem should be merely cosmetic...?

Comment: I gave you an answer to the question as it is now. I think that a more elaborate discussion might be better suited for the [jOOQ User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user). Interesting idea, anyway!

Comment: @LukasEder Recalling from memeory - `SQLServerDatabase.is2012()` was returning true. [#2624](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2624) fixes it.

Comment: My bad. I thought that this fix was merged to [3.1.1](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2625) already, but 3.1.1 hasn't been published yet.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure if this will meet your actual requirements, but using an [`ExecuteListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ExecuteListener.html), you can hook into jOOQ's general query execution lifecycle and inject some behaviour into jOOQ's exception handling. Some examples are given here:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners

In particular, your custom `ExecuteListener` might look like this:

```
public class MyListener extends DefaultExecuteListener {

    @Override
    public void exception(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        // Put some logic here
    }
}
```

Note, this currently won't prevent the throwing of the exception, itself.