# How to print out Exceptions in jOOQ

Tags: java, exception, logging, java-8, jooq

I'm running a batch insert with jOOQ. It worked until today, when I switched from `java.util.Date` to `org.joda.time.DateTime` and added a converter to jOOQ.

Now I keep getting exceptions, but jOOQ is too stubborn to print out the exception. How do I get jOOQ to give me details on the exception?

I'm already using `DEBUG` logging level.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: @Thilo I do not know. That is exactly why I'm asking how to print the exception details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18940954/608454

Basically using a `ExecutionListener` which binds on the `exception` method. Here is the manual page for it http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/

Comment: Would you mind posting that exception? Could be something that could be improved in jOOQ...

Comment: @LukasEder I already managed to fix the error which caused the exception and rollbacking is a bit of a pain. But I'm quite sure it was a field conversion error. I passed a `org.joda.time.DateTime` and jOOQ expected a `java.sql.Date`. My `forcedType` rules didn't work and thus it hadn't generated the right code

Comment: Oh, I see. For some reason, I had read `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead of `org.joda.time.DateTime` in your question, which is why I thought there might have been a problem in jOOQ

Comment: @LukasEder TBH I do find there is a problem in jOOQ if I need to write a listener class to see a stacktrace when a DataAccessException happens. Database errors should not be swallowed up be the abstraction layer.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. But from your question right now, it's not trivial to reproduce the error... There are several batch APIs. Perhaps, not all of them are flawed.